# Lambda get from many to many table

Tags: linq, lambda

I have three tables connected.

Person -> Trip -> Hotel

I would like to retrieve all the people and the name of the hotel they have traveled to.
Every person might have been on multiple trips and might have stayed a several hotels on their trip.
How do I do this in Lambda syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Persons.Select(p=> new {
                  Person = p, 
                  Hotels = p.SelectMany(p=>p.Trips).SelectMany(t=>t.Hotels)
                  }).ToList();
```